# add class along with append in jquery

Tags: jquery, append

I have to append an image to a div. I need to add style to this. I used the below code but the class is not added to the image. Please help me to solve this.

```
jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
    jQuery('#imagenn').addClass('featuredimage').append('<img src="' + val+ '" />');
});
```

Comment: the class will going to add to `div` not image .Instead directly add class to image i.e :  `jQuery('#imagenn').append('<img class="featuredimage" src="' + val+ '" />');`

Comment: from the code the class will be added to the container with id `imagenn`. What does your relevant html look like?